# Оператор присваивания в C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Есть несколько моментов в описании оператора присваивания (assignment operator) в стандарте языка, которые мне не ясны, и хотелось бы их прояснить.

n4659, 8.18/1:

> [...] In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the **value computation of the right and left operands**, and before the value computation of the assignment expression. The right operand is sequenced before the left operand. With respect to an **indeterminately-sequenced** function call, the operation of a compound assignment is a single evaluation. [*Note*: Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any single compound assignment operator. —*end note*]

Вопрос 1. Что такое **value computation** и выполняется ли оно с точки зрения стандарта для левого и правого операндов в следующем коде:

```
a = 1;
```

Вопрос 2. Что имеется в виду, когда говорится о неопределённой упорядоченности вызова функции? Хотелось бы увидеть пример, с участием присваивания и вызова функции в одном выражении, где вызов функции неопределённо упорядочен, относительно чего-либо.

n4659, 8.18/8:

> If the value being stored in an object is read via another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have the same type, otherwise the behavior is undefined. [*Note*: This restriction applies to the relationship between the left and right sides of the assignment operation; it is not a statement about how the target of the assignment may be aliased in general. See 6.10. —*end note*]

Вопрос 3. Хотелось бы увидеть пример, который попадает под описание приведённой выше цитаты.

---

Дополнение к вопросу 1.

Наверное, больший смысл имеет поставить вопрос следующим образом: **всегда ли** с точки зрения стандарта языка выполняется *value computation* для операндов оператора присваивания? И если нет, то когда выполняется, а когда нет?

Дело то вот в чём. В первой цитате в этом вопросе говорится, что присваивание происходит после того, как произойдёт value computation обоих операндов. А ещё говорится, что правый операнд упорядочен перед левым (т.е. value computations + side effects, ассоциированные с правым операндом, произойдут до value computations + side effects ассоциированных с левым операндом).

Таким образом, **если** в операторе присваивания всегда происходит value computation левого операнда перед собственно присвоением, то правый операнд всегда упорядочен перед присвоением.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«value computation» это процесс вычисления значения выражения, т.е. получение его результата. К примеру, пусть у нас есть `int i = 0`, тогда вычисленное выражение `i++` вернёт `0`. Тут важен тот факт, что `i++` содержит побочные эффекты (side effects). Так вот, имея *вычисленное* вышеозначенное выражение, мы не гарантируем, что к нему в то же время были применены требуемые изменения (инкремент). Почему это может быть важно? Возьмём для этого стандарт до 17 года. В нём выражение: `i = i++` имеет неопределённое поведение, потому что инкремент для `i` никак не упорядочен по отношению к присваиванию: он может произойти до или же после.

С другой стороны, если мы возьмём выражение `++i`, то в нём побочные эффекты применяются до вычисления выражения, что делает такое выражение `i = ++i` рабочим и не содержащим неопределённого поведения.

---

Теперь ко второму вопросу. Давайте предположим у нас есть глобальная переменная: `long long global = 0;` и функция `auto foo() {return global += 1;}`. Для примера нам так же понадобится такая функция `void ignore(long long, long long)` и C++17 (исключительно ради гарантии неопределённой упорядоченности (indeterminately sequenced) вычисления аргументов функции).

Наконец, рассмотрим такой код: `ignore(global += BIG_NUMBER, foo())`, так вот, в теории, если убрать это правило, то могла бы получится следующая ситуация (на какой-нибудь платформе, где запись `long long` будет в несколько инструкций): мы начинаем записывать в наш `global` извне, записываем часть, но тут происходит переключение на код `foo` (так решил компилятор) и переписывает то, что мы записали. После чего мы продолжаем запись и в нашей переменной `global` лежит мусор. Т.е. это правило запрещает перемежение (interleaving, overlapping) вычисления выражений, и компилятор не имеет права сделать то, что я описал в предыдущем предложении.

Но это всё теория, потому что стандарт явно запрещает (C++14[intro.object]p13) перемежение всех выражений, за исключением неупорядоченных (unsequenced), поэтому подобные уточнения мне кажутся лишними.

---

Третья цитата запрещает такое:

```
int i = 0;
char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&i);
// Вот тут проблема
*ptr = static_cast<char>(i);
```

Т.е. слева и справа не должно быть двух объектов, которые указывают на одну область памяти, но имеют разные типы.

---

По поводу дополнения: тут просто стоит привести цитату из C++17[intro.object]p15:

> <...> An expression X is said to be sequenced before an expression Y
>   if every value computation and every side effect associated with the
>   expression X is sequenced before every value computation and every
>   side effect associated with the expression Y <...>

И этого будет достаточно. Согласно правилам, введённым в C++17, правая часть выражения присваивания упорядочена до (sequenced before):

> The right operand is sequenced before the left operand

Это является ключом к пониманию: прежде чем мы присвоим новое значение, или даже начнём вычислять то, чему мы там присваиваем, всё, что стоит справа должно отработать. Это правило делает код, `i = i++` правильным, хотя до C++17 это было неопределённым поведением.

Comment: По поводу ответа на второй вопрос. Стандарт говорит также, что "For each function invocation `F`, for every evaluation `A` that occurs within `F` and every evaluation `B` that does not occur within `F` but is evaluated on the same thread and as part of the same signal handler (if any), either `A` is sequenced before `B` or `B` is sequenced before `A`." Я так понимаю, это ещё одна гарантия из которой следует, что приведённый вами пример невозможен?

Comment: @wololo, эта цитата дополняет невозможность перемежения, да. Но она больше относится к аргументам функции, хотя, наверное, её можно привязать и к нашему примеру. Правда она несколько менее требовательна чем то, что описано в _C++14[intro.object]p13_, поэтому я бы не стал применять её к нашему случаю.

Comment: По поводу вашего дополнения к ответу. Всё-таки я не понимаю :) Да стандарт говорит, что правый операнд упорядочен перед левым. Но, у меня сложилось впечатление, что стандарт языка явно не упорядочивает side effects связанные с вычислением правого операнда и собственно присвоение (возможно, я не прав?). Поэтому я не понимаю почему верно, что "прежде чем мы присвоим новое значение, [...] всё, что стоит справа должно отработать."

Comment: Если оператор присваивания может(???) не делать value computation левого операнда, и у левого операнда нет side effects, то может(???) произойти следующая последовательность действий: делаем value computation правого операнда -> делаем присваивание -> вычисляем результат присваивания -> делаем side effects правого операнда.

Comment: @wololo, исправил третий пример. Дальше: впечатление неверное, упорядочено всё, в том числе и побочные эффекты. Вычисление значение (val comp) всегда происходит, вопрос лишь в какой момент времени. Последовательность у Вас описана неверно, читайте внимательно цитату, что я привел. Правая часть должна быть полностью вычислена(val comp & side effects), до того, как дело дойдёт до левой

Answer (score 3):

Как слева, так и справа от оператора присваивания могут быть более сложные сущности, нежели указаны в вашем примере. Например, слева может быть функция, которая возвращает ссылку, а справа функция возвращающее значение. Вот вызов этих функций для получения значения правой и левой части и есть value computation. Для вашего случая можно сказать, что слева вычисляется адрес переменной `a`, а справа значение литерала `1`.

Фраза про "*indeterminately-sequenced function call*" говорит о том, что составные операторы типа `+=`, `*=` и т.д. стоит рассматривать как одиночное (неделимое) вычисление при использовании в качестве аргумента функции. Например, при вызове следующей функции:

```
f (a() += b(), c())
```

вызов `c()` не может произойти между вызовами `a()` и `b()`.

По третьему вопросу - представьте, что у вас есть массив байтов. И вы имеете два указателя более тяжелого типа нежели байт, на данные из этого массива. При этом разыменование этих указателей будет использовать некоторую общую часть исходного массива, то есть иметь пересечение. Вот такие разыменованные указатели и нельзя использовать в присваивании.

Comment: По второму: это правило про другое, то, что Вы говорите описано отдельным пунктом в том же разделе.

Comment: По поводу третьего вопроса. Вы имеете ввиду, что нельзя делать так (strict aliasing и требования по выравниванию для типов не учитываем): `char mass[16] = {};` `*reinterpret_cast<short  *>(mass) = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(mass)`, и так: `*reinterpret_cast<int *>(mass) = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(mass + 1);`

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии предполагается, что `sizeof(int) > 1`.  Но не запрещает делать так (опять же без учёта strict aliasing и требований по выравниванию типов):  `char mass[16] = {};` `*reinterpret_cast<short *>(mass) = *reinterpret_cast<short *>(mass + sizeof(short))`, и так `*reinterpret_cast<short *>(mass) = *reinterpret_cast<short *>(mass) + 1`?

Comment: @wololo да, Вы мы меня правильно поняли. Надеюсь я тоже правильно понял стандарт :)